# AWS DescribeRouteTables not returning implicit associations

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to fetch implicit associations (between subnets and route_tables), but according to this documentation [api describe route tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeRouteTables.html) , it seems that only explicit associations are returned. Is there another way to query and get this information.
For a given subnet_id I want the explicit and implicit associations too.
So far, and I've been using `boto3.resource()` and `boto3.client()` but none of those provide me the "chain/path" to get this.

Answer (score 0):

I found that, If there is not a explicit route association, It will take the main route implicitly. So, for that scenario:
`[vpc]->[route table]->[igw|natgw]`

See [EC2.Client.describe_route_tables](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_route_tables)